# Why these 2 pieces of code give different results (grid-row)?

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to understand how does CSS grid work and I don't understand why the following codes produces different results:

```css
.item20 {
    grid-row-start: 4;
    grid-row: span 3;
}
```

And the next one I think is the shorthand:

```css
.item20 {
    grid-row: 4 / span 3;
}
```

I want to have this item starting at row 4 and have a height of 3 rows, but the result is different when I choose first code.

First Code:

[image: First Code]

Second Code:

[image: Second Code]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you use `grid-row: span 3;` in the first code, it overwrites the `grid-row-start: 4;` with the values:

`grid-row-start: span 3; grid-row-end: auto;`

So, item 20 gets expanded from its original position to 3 rows down.

So, to get it right you have to use `grid-row-end: span 3;` instead of `grid-row: span 3;` because `grid-row` itself is the shorthand property for `grid-row-start` and `grid-row-end` values.